# Python serial connection - segmentation fault (Windows fatal exception: access violation) Smart metering software

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, serial-port, access-violation

First SO question so bear with me;
I'm trying to connect to a Landis+Gyr electrical meter, using open-source smart metering software written in Python.
The Python code can be found [here](https://github.com/Gurux/Gurux.DLMS.Python). I have access to an optical programming eye so I'm trying to use a serial connection.

Confirmed I am executing the correct commands and have all the necessary files, etc. But when I run the commands in the terminal I get 'Windows fatal exception: access violation', some trace, and then 'Segmentation fault'

I have narrowed the problem down to the last line here, I think...

```
def close(self):
    #pylint: disable=broad-except
    if self.media and self.media.isOpen():
        print("DisconnectRequest")
        reply = GXReplyData()
        try:
            #Release is called only for secured connections.
            #All meters are not supporting Release and it's causing
            #problems.
            if self.client.interfaceType == InterfaceType.WRAPPER or self.client.ciphering.security != Security.NONE:
                self.readDataBlock(self.client.releaseRequest(), reply)
        except Exception:
            pass
            #  All meters don't support release.
        reply.clear()
        self.readDLMSPacket(self.client.disconnectRequest(), reply)
        self.media.close()
```

If I comment `self.media.close()` out I no longer get 'Windows fatal exception: access violation' but the script does not execute correctly.

Any feedback on what could be going wrong here would be much appreciated.

Windows 10 64bit
Python 3.7

Edit: Turns out it was an issue with the optical eye used to communicated with the smart meter. The Gurux software was unable to communicate with the driver correctly. This was quickly resolved by the Gurux team.
Thanks all for the comments!

Comment: Could you add the detail of the failure you encounter?

Comment: Adding a delay between the readDLMSPacket and the close could possibly resolve your access violation problem.